# Issues with saving datas in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I have a website with a settings page / form. In this page, I have 3 nested forms, and my problem concerns all three of them.

These nested form are there to allow the user to tell what professionnal skill he's good in (HTML, PHP, Ruby, you name them). And with that, they can select a number between 0 and 100, and also a color. But for now, all I want to do is to be able to save these datas.

Here is how I proceed to save one of these nested form (the two others are exactly the same with small differences to differentiate each other:

**setting.rb and stat1.rb (model)**

```
# setting.rb
has_many :stat1s, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :stat1s, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |att| att['name'].blank? }
# stat1.rb
belongs_to :setting, optional: true
```

**settings_controller.rb (relevant part)**

```
  # GET /settings/new
  def new
    @setting = Setting.new
    @setting.stat1s.build
    @setting.stat2s.build
    @setting.stat3s.build
  end

  # GET /settings/1/edit
  def edit
    @setting.stat1s.build
    @setting.stat2s.build
    @setting.stat3s.build
  end

# ...

private 

def setting_params

params.require(:setting).permit( [...], stat1s_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :setting_id, :percentage, :name, :color])
```

**application.js (relevant part)**

```
    $('form').on('click', '.add_stat1, function(event) {
        $('.stat1').append($(this).data('stat1'));
        return event.preventDefault()
    });
```

SO here is my issue: when I load the form, the nested form generates the following by default: `<input type="text" name="setting[stat1][name]" id="setting_stat1_name />`. However, when I add a new field, the html generated looks like the following: `<input type="text" name="setting[stat1s_attributes][69856526209200][name]" id="setting_stat1s_attributes_69856526209200_name">`

As you can see, somehow, "_attributes" is getting added and I can't figure why, how and where. This makes the nested only saving only the first element, but not saving anything else after, and not making anything else showing after this.

How can I get rid of this?

Thank you in advance